# Apache redirects (<whatever>.mydomain.<whatever> to mydomain.com)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In a virtual host in apache I would like to redirect all requests to `<anything>.mydomain.<anything>` to just `mydomain.com`.

However, the below rewrite rule is ignored for some reason. Why?

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^.*mydomain.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this rule to redirect every request with a host other than `example.com` to `example.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

`%{REMOTE_HOST}` refers to the name of the computer that's accessing your website - it's "remote" from the *server's* perspective. As Gumbo pointed out, you should be using `%{HTTP_HOST}`.